# event.preventdefault() removes question mark from url

Tags: jquery, forms, url

I have a get form that loads a php file into a div. However the required event.preventdefault() removes the question mark and the form parameters from the url. How can I prevent this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#df').submit(function(){
    var month_ddchart = $('#dm').val();
    var year_ddchart = $('#dy').val();
    source_ddchart = '/data/ddc-'+month_ddchart+'-'+year_ddchart+'-body.php';
    $('#content_box').load(source_ddchart);
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `event` to the function arguments, to actually have it available within the function, like so:

```
$("#myForm1").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: changing `$('#df').submit(function(){` to `$('#df').submit(function(event){` doesn't solve the problem (#df is the form name and id)

Comment: It seems you also need to use ```return false;```. I have updated my question accordingly

Comment: Sadly, that also isn't the solution.